# Facebook chat history

Tags: empathy

I would like to ask, if it is possible in Empathy to have facebook chat history, because Empathy shows only messages sent/received specifically on this device and not from my other PC or my android. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histories and logs are stored locally, which is why you can only see your local exchanges. What you want would require a server-based (or at least shared) history, which Empathy cannot provide since it is not installed on all your devices (you probably use various clients). By the way, I don't think it offers synchronisation, even if installed everywhere, since it has no proper account management (it only connects you to other services on which YOU have an account).

In order to have a shared and synchronised history system, you need the server to handle the storage, and well... it does not. (*just kidding! Facebook has everything stored, they just wont tell.*)

Comment: I found out that FBMessenger does this, but problem with it is that it can't run in background, nor have any unity notifications. I guess I can't have best of both worlds until I learn some programming language properly :D Thank you very much for your answer.